# How to properly write a POST method for text input in a game?

Tags: python, post, django-rest-framework

I am very new to django and I am writing an API for a game in which players tag pictures (resources). I am having some trouble with the post request, with which a tagging instance can be stored in the database.

Here is the model for the Tagging:

**models.py**

```
class Tagging(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    origin = models.URLField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')
```

This is my game view with the post request down below. What I am trying to do is send an empty gameround and gamesession object that are then 'filled' with data in the post request.

**views.py**

```
class ARTigoGameView(APIView):
    """
    API View that retrieves the game - empty game session to be filled with the necessary data and sent back to the server, retrieves a random resource per round,
    allows users to post tags that are verified and saved to the Tagging table
    """

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        controller = GameViewController()
        
        gameround = Gameround.objects.none()
        gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround, many=True)

        random_resource = Resource.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
        resource_serializer = ResourceSerializer(random_resource)

        # A previously played gameround for this resource is coordinated for Tag verification
        coordinated_gameround = controller.get_gameround_matching_resource(random_resource.id)

        gamesession = Gamesession.objects.none()
        gamesession_serializer = GamesessionSerializer(gamesession, many=True)

        return Response({'resource': resource_serializer.data,
                         'coordinated_gameround': coordinated_gameround,
                         'gameround': gameround_serializer.data,
                         'gamesession': gamesession_serializer.data
                         })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        controller = GameViewController()
        id = controller.generate_random_id(Tagging)
        current_user = request.user  # user instance
        gameround = request.data.get('gameround')
        resource = request.data.get('resource')
        tag = request.data.get('tag')
        created = request.data.get('created')
        score = request.data.get('score')
        origin = request.data.get('origin')

        saved_tagging = None

        serializer = TaggingSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            saved_tagging = Tagging.objects.create(id=id,
                                                   user=current_user,
                                                   gameround=gameround,
                                                   resource=resource,
                                                   tag=tag,
                                                   created=created,
                                                   score=score,
                                                   origin=origin
                                                   )
            saved_tagging.save()
            serializer = TaggingSerializer(saved_tagging)
            return Response({'status': 'success', 'tagging': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        if saved_tagging is None:
            return Response({'tagging': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        else:
            return Response(saved_tagging, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have kept testing it with Postman and am getting the following Value error at the moment:

```
Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0xffff8383c550>": "Tagging.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong about this post request or what I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you get a `AnonymousUser` then that means you are unauthenticated. How does the user that hits this API get authenticated?

Comment: @BrianDestura this is what I have in my settings.py 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',) Doesn't this mean that any user is allowed?

Comment: Yes any user is allowed, even unauthenticated ones (in this case you get an `Anonymous` user. But your `Tagging` model's `user` field requires a `CustomUser` though that's why you get the error.